# Can a compound sentence contains more than 2 tenses?

Tags: grammar, writing

Can I use two verb-tenses in one compound sentence?

For example:
*"I sent an email yesterday, and are waiting the reply now"*

Is it correct way in writing?

Thanks

Comment: Yes regarding the title of you question. No regarding your question in the body of your question. "I sent an email yesterday and *am* waiting for a reply." OR "I sent an email yesterday and am awaiting a reply."

Answer (score 1):

You can change tenses, yes, but your sentence has some minor errors. You should change *are* to *am* because the subject is *I*. *Wait* does not take a direct object—you want *wait for* or *await*.

> I sent an email yesterday, and <del>are</del> **am** waiting **for** the reply now.
>
> I sent an email yesterday, and am <del>waiting</del> **awaiting** the reply now.